# Validation rule to check consecutive characters in field

Tags: apex, validation, validation-rule

I need to throw an error if there are three consecutive characters in field value.

like aaa,bbb,ccc,eee,AAA,BBB etc.

I am using below condition to check but dont think this is good solution.

```
OR(CONTAINS( FirstName ,"aaa" ),
CONTAINS( FirstName ,"bbb" ),
CONTAINS( FirstName ,"ccc" )
```

Could anyone please help

Answer (score 6):

use [REGEX](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_functions_i_z.htm&type=5) validation formula. The following regex expression `(\w)\1\1+` checks if there is 3 same word constituent characters in a row  (case-insensitive). You can check this regex online [here](https://regex101.com/r/IVRvWg/1) (nice service to play around with regex).

Create validation rule with the following formula

```
REGEX(FirstName, "(\\w)\\1\\1+")
```

Comment: You don't need to explicitly set the case insensitive flag?

Comment: @AdrianLarson if I understood question correctly, this regex should be case-sensitive.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense, but I did not know the `REGEX` validation function was case insensitive by default. In Apex, you have to set that flag using `(?i)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to have Regex like this:

```
REGEX(Name, '^([a-z])\\1\\1*')
```

Not tested properly. Please test before use.

> **Update:**
>
> [a-z] : Will seek the alphabets(smaller case).
>
> 1, 1 was for the same occurences. Since we need 3 consecutive(first alphabet and its next 2 times(min) occurrence is required.
>
> Since I have used **^** it will check at the start of the string.
>
> However, main crux of this answer, is the letting know the way of Regex in validation rules.
>
> Answer from @Oleksandr Berehovskiy gives more correct regex.

Comment: Thanks for that ,but i need to throw an error if those consucative characters are in anywhere in string(Name).Currently if i only enter the'aaaa' then only error is coming if i enter 'aaa testsaj' then error is not coming.

Comment: @Ysr Shk, use like this without aproper explanation is not very helpful. mind elaborating? thanks

Comment: thanks glls. Will try from now to have explanation to my answers! :)